# jqueryui widget factory change method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am writing a jqueryui widget, and I want to get at some widget data when the widget changes (using _trigger). I am using the widget as follows:

```
$("#myDiv").myWidget({
    change: function(e) {
        alert($("#filter").myWidget('getWidgetData'));
        // do something with the widget data.
    }
});
```

This code works (the alert fires and show the widget data when the widget calls _trigger). However, is this the correct/best way to get at the widget data inside the change callback ? For isntance,  I can't seem to call this.getWidgetData, or e.getWidgetData.

Comment: Nobody ? Is the question worded badly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attached your data to the change event you triggered. You should have something like :

```
this._trigger('change', e);
```

and could use :

```
this._trigger('change', e, { widgetData: this.getWidgetData() });
```

The `_trigger` function accepts `A hash of data associated with the event.` as its third arg  as decribed in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-_trigger).

And your code will become :

```
$("#myDiv").myWidget({
    change: function(e, data) {
        alert(data.widgetData);
        // do something with the widget data.
    }
});
```